# Applying Background Image to Table Row - Bug

Tags: html, css

I see there are a couple of posts about this around, including one on SO. However none of them answer the question, I am posting a newer one with an image that demonstrates the problem in 4 browsers.

[image: testcase image]

FireFox renders the background image on the TR as I would like but as you can see none of the others do..

Does anybody have any ideas? At this point it looks like I need to go back to the drawing borad.

ps. adding backgound:none or background-image:none to TD doesn't fix this.

This is the code for my test case:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title></title>

    <style type="text/css">
        body
        {
            background-color:#aaa;
        }

        table
        {
            background-color:#fff;   
        } 

        tbody tr
        {
            height:80px;
            background:#aaa url("Content/LM_DROPDOWN_BG_BUTT_01.png") no-repeat bottom ;
            position:relative;
        }

        tbody tr td
        {
            background-image:none;
        }
    </style>


</head>
<body>


    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="width:200">Col1</th>
                <th style="width:200">Col2</th>
                <th style="width:200">Col3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Row 1 Col 1</td>
                <td>Row 1 Col 2</td>
                <td>Row 1 Col 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Row 2 Col 1</td>
                <td>Row 2 Col 2</td>
                <td>Row 2 Col 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Row 3 Col 1</td>
                <td>Row 3 Col 2</td>
                <td>Row 3 Col 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If your doctype isn't `<!DOCTYPE html>` then this isn't HTML5

Comment: My original was HTML5. I mocked up this test case to make everything simpler and clearer.. thought I had visual studio to default to HTML5.. obviously not for new HTML docs.. it's the same problem either way

Answer (score 0):

Would nested table work for you?

[see the 3rd row](http://jsfiddle.net/7DNQ2/)

Works cross-browser. Not cute (nested table!), but gets the job done.

Styling `<tr>`is hum, problematic, especially cross-browser. After all, a `tr` can only contains `td`.  It's not made to support other stuff (try `<table><tr><td>1</td></tr><div>2</div></table>` for fun).

Also, give Opera some love.

**edit**:however, you'll have to either have the same (fixed) width for the nested `<td>` (or the content), otherwise, the width of the `<td>` will be broken (not the same).

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I doubt nested tables is a very semantic solution. Having a nested table for every row can't be a good solution. I think I shall forget about having bg images on the tr elements and dfind another way to create my functionality